# Oracle query - more recirds in result as in table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I would like select data form table with additional rows (030) and it should contain all possible combinations of other columns

For example:

```
 Select * from table where row in ('010,'020','030')

comp       period       row       column        value
1          30.06.2017   010       020           500
1          30.06.2017   020       020           300
2          30.06.2017   010       020           400
3          30.06.2017   020       020           100
```

And the results should be like this

```
comp       period       row       column        value
1          30.06.2017   010       020           500
1          30.06.2017   020       020           300
2          30.06.2017   010       020           400
2          30.06.2017   020       020           (null)
3          30.06.2017   020       020           100
3          30.06.2017   010       020           (null)
1          30.06.2017   030       020           (null)
2          30.06.2017   030       020           (null)
3          30.06.2017   030       020           (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the current results.  I think you want:

```
Select cpr.*, r.row, t.value
from (select distinct comp, period, column from t) cpr cross join
     (select '010' as row from dual union all
      select '020' as row from dual union all
      select '030' as row from dual 
     ) r left join
     t
     on t.comp = cpr.comp and t.period = cpr.period and t.column = cpr.column and t.row = cpr.row;
```

Comment: With this example i can't get rows with row code 030 as the result of
`select distinct row from t where row in ('010, '020', '030')` will not show rows with code 030 because there are no rows with code 030 in the table

Comment: @ErkkoKõrgema . . . In that case, just list the values explicitly.